# Get graphics information from font file. How to develop font parser similar to PDFView's font parsers?

Tags: c#, fonts, typography, pdfsharp, rasterizing

I am trying to convert text into graphics using c#.

My input is character string and output is bitmap with the input text.

After lot of search I found some ways to do it, I found some techiques which uses this kind of techinque. 
For Example While creating Captcha, we have to print the character in the bitmap.

But for that I should have the font installed in my windows.

I can not perform such operation without installing the font.

I have .ttf file with me but I dont want to install it because my work for that font is temporary only.

Is there any way where I can extract out the Font's graphical information by providing the Character?

I have also found font parser code http://swinglabs.java.sun.com/hudson/job/PDFRenderer%20Weekly%20Build/javadoc/com/sun/pdfview/font/package-summary.html

Can anyone please provide me how to develpo similar thing using c#.Net?

Or

From where can I get the algorithm to parce font?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PrivateFontCollection Class to use fonts that are not installed in Windows.

No need to parse them yourself.